# "Get Unique Values" formula adds a row of "0"'s to the end of the table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

I was trying to implement [this](https://exceljet.net/formula/extract-unique-items-from-a-list) formula into my book to condense a larger table into a list format. I cannot use pivot tables because I need to do complicated calculations in later columns after I have achieved this condensed list.

The table looks like: [image: this]

The Row# Column is filled by an Array Formula:

`{=IFERROR(MATCH(0,COUNTIF(INDIRECT("$F$1:$F$" & ROW(E3)-1),$A$1:$A$4000),0),"")}`

which translates to: "Get the row # of the first item in column A that isnt found in Column F above my current position"

The other three columns are filled by: `=IFERROR(INDIRECT("A" & $E2),"")`

My problem is that the last row of the table is always filled with `0,0,0` because for some unknown reason it matches the first blank row as a unique value.

**My question is: How do I add a criteria that the unique value is not blank or 0?**

As for clamping the search range, the table is generated by a program and has a variable and unknown number of rows so I cannot manually set the table range to the last non-blank row. I put `$A$1:$A$4000` so that I won't miss any of the table's entries.

If there is a way to automatically determine the last row, that would also solve the problem.

Edit: I also realize that the list is not being condensed properly, I'm working towards getting it to compare all three values instead of just the first value.

Edit2: I got it to compare all three values, but the `0,0,0` problem is still there if anyone has ideas about that.

`{=IFERROR(MATCH(0,COUNTIF(INDIRECT("$F$1:$F$" & ROW(E2)-1),$A$1:$A$4000)*COUNTIF(INDIRECT("$G$1:$G$" & ROW(E2)-1),$B$1:$B$4000)*COUNTIF(INDIRECT("$H$1:$H$" & ROW(E2)-1),$C$1:$C$4000),0),"")}`

Comment: If you have Office 365, you can use the `UNIQUE` function.  And it is likely your calculations and aggregation can be done using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365.  Also, if you use a `Table` and structured references, it can automatically adjust to the used range.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thanks! But unfortunately I'm on Excel 2007, but if I can't figure it out, I might beg my boss to move us up to a newer version.

Comment: In that case, given the complexity with multiple columns and downstream complicated formulas, I would suggest a VBA solution (or you could upgrade and use Power Query).

Comment: Just as an example, to create a table of unique items, taking into account all three columns, the formula would be `=UNIQUE(myTable)` in a single cell.  The entire Table would `Spill` into the appropriate sized range.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I 100% agree that VBA would be the way to go. But this table is part of a template file that must be in `.xlsx` format. The program outputs the data in Sheet1, and I was hoping this table would be in Sheet2 as a summary, without needing to load in a VBA addon.

Comment: With a more up-to-date version, you could use Power Query, which would still allow saving as an `.xlsx`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I really wish my office would move to a new version. For now, I've just set the number format to "#" to hide the 0's.

Comment: Here's another thought that should work in 2007.  `Data=>Advanced Filter=>Unique Records Only`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are dealing with Excel 2007, and want a table of unique values, I suggest the `Advanced Filter`.

Setup your Data as a **Table**

Navigate to the worksheet where you want the results of the "filter"

Then `Data=>Advanced Filter`

[image]

**Voila!**

[image]

If you have more than three columns, but you only want to apply the unique filter on the first three, you can use a formula for the filter criteria.

For example:

```
    A1: Unique Formula
    A2: =COUNTIFS($A$7:$A7,$A7,$B$7:$B7,$B7,$C$7:C7,$C7)=1
```

*you can visualize the effects of this filter by entering it into some helper column, adjacent to the table in row7, and then filling down the length of the table. If you did this, you could use the autofilter, and just filter on `1`*

[image]

[image]

**Voila!**

[image]

Comment: This seems like a good option, How can I use the "Filter list, in-place" option? How do I specify that I'm only looking for unique values in 3 columns of the table and not the others? Whenever I press OK, nothing changes and I suspect its because each row has some uniqueness to it, in other columns that I'm not trying to filter.

Comment: @Toddleson  You didn't mention that you had more than the three columns.  To use the Advanced Filter and limit the "unique" filter to just the three columns, we need to use a formula criteria.  Of course, you will be losing some data that is in the rows that get filtered out.  And to filter in place, you merely check that option. You may need to be on the same sheet.  I will edit my answer to show the filter method.